# Record vlc stream using python

Tags: python, video, stream, vlc, recording

I want to open a VLC stream and record it through a python script. Is there anyone with some experience with this? I know there is a API [libvlc](https://wiki.videolan.org/Python_bindings/) that can be used.

Comment: Maybe you should use the ffmpeg to do that, it's so easy. http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Should I use pyffmpeg?